# MySQL add count to query as column

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I would like to run a query that brings back each record that meets a certain criteria, as well as give me total number of times that occurs in my table.

So if I run:

```
SELECT id from history where id like "%CLM%";
```

I get each instance of an `id` from my table where "CLM" is somewhere in that `id`.  What I want in the column NEXT to that is a count of how many times that particular record was found, and I can't seem to figure out how to do that.

What I'm looking for would be something like this:

```
╔══════╦═══════╗
║  id  ║ count ║
╠══════╬═══════╣
║ CLM1 ║     1 ║
║ CLM2 ║     5 ║
║ CLM3 ║    13 ║
╚══════╩═══════╝
```

I've tried `SELECT id, count(id) from history` but it returns this:

```
╔══════╦══════════╗
║  id  ║ count    ║
╠══════╬══════════╣
║      ║ 12258432 ║
╚══════╩══════════╝
```

How do I write this query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you saw, you can use the `count` function to count rows. The part you're missing, however, is breaking down this result per `id`, which can be done with a `group by` clause:

```
SELECT   id, COUNT(*)
FROM     history
WHERE    id LIKE '%CLM%'
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Ahhh - I'll go read up on how to use group by statements.  This works perfectly too.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT id, count(*)
 from history 
 where id like "%CLM%"
 GROUP BY id
```

Comment: while this may be a correct answer, it doesn't offer any explanation why this works, thus lowering the value of the answer.

Comment: @keda *lowering the value* is absolutely different from *downvote*, but that is up to you

Comment: maybe, but this site is as much about teaching as is it is about answers.  Mureinik gave a good explanation to the same solution which caused Brian to go read about `group by` statement.  Brian will gain much more from that than simply implementing a solution and not understanding it.  Also, this not providing an explanation will not benefit people who are looking for a similar answer in the future.

Comment: as I said, your right, your opinion, your downvote. have a good day

Comment: Brian will :)  Having said that, I countered the downvote with an upvote since if your answer WERE the only one, it still would have helped me because I still would have gone and looked up info on `group by` since that was the obvious part I was missing.  It still does help though to add an explanation of why.  I do appreciate you answer though.

Comment: @BrianPowell thank you very much, I appreciate a lot your opinion and upvote. good luck with your project!

Comment: I agree with @Keda, so I downvtoing and recommending for deletion